# Write operation on memory mapped IO gives segmentation fault

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, mmap, memory-mapping

I'm accessing UART by mapping its physical base address to user space. Read operation is successful but write operation give segmentation fault. Below is my code

```
#define     READ_REG32(reg)     ( *((volatile int *) (reg)) )
#define     WRITE_REG32(reg,value)     ( *((volatile int *) (reg)) = value )

static int Write_on_uart()  
{  
    void * map_base;  
    FILE *f;  
    int type,fd;  

    fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC);  
    if (fd) {  
        printf("Success to open /dev/mem fd=%08x\n", fd);  
    }  
    else {  
        printf("Fail to open /dev/mem fd=%08x\n", fd);    
    }  
    map_base = mmap(0, ALLOC_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0x21E8000);

    type = READ_REG32(map_base + UCR1);
    printf("READ_REG32 successful\n");


    printf("Going to WRITE_REG32 register\n");

    WRITE_REG32(map_base + UTXD,'R'); ///Got segementation fault
    printf("WRITE_REG32 successful\n");

    close(fd);  
    munmap(map_base, ALLOC_SIZE);  

    printf("reg32[%08x] = value[%08x] \n", map_base, type);  

    type = (type & ( 1 << 27 )) >> 27 ;  

    printf("reg32[%08x] = value[%08x] \n", map_base, type);  

    return type;  
}
```

Segmentation fault is below:

```
, *pte=00000000, *ppte=00000000
[   50.354260] CPU: 0 PID: 401 Comm: raw_uart_access Not tainted 4.9.84-+gb2a7f2f #4
[   50.381000] Hardware name: Freescale i.MX6 UltraLite (Device Tree)
[   50.397017] task: 9229d140 task.stack: 9271a000
[   50.411233] PC is at 0x1057c
[   50.423459] LR is at 0x10574
[   50.435355] pc : [<0001057c>]    lr : [<00010574>]    psr: 200d0010
[   50.435355] sp : 7e8b4c80  ip : 00000000  fp : 7e8b4c9c
[   50.464647] r10: 76f61fac  r9 : 00000000  r8 : 00000000
[   50.478608] r7 : 00000000  r6 : 00010408  r5 : 00000000  r4 : 00010634
[   50.493738] r3 : ffffffff  r2 : 00000010  r1 : 76f60210  r0 : ffffffff
[   50.508645] Flags: nzCv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode USER_32  ISA ARM  Segment user
[   50.532259] Control: 10c5387d  Table: 9297806a  DAC: 00000055
[   50.546485] CPU: 0 PID: 401 Comm: raw_uart_access Not tainted 4.9.84-+gb2a7f2f #4
[   50.570395] Hardware name: Freescale i.MX6 UltraLite (Device Tree)
[   50.585015] Backtrace: 
[   50.595863] [<8010bd3c>] (dump_backtrace) from [<8010c014>] (show_stack+0x18/0x1c)
[   50.620055]  r7:00000017 r6:600d0113 r5:00000000 r4:80c1c9f0
[   50.634156] [<8010bffc>] (show_stack) from [<8042ed84>] (dump_stack+0x90/0xa4)
[   50.657979] [<8042ecf4>] (dump_stack) from [<80108a98>] (show_regs+0x14/0x18)
[   50.673778]  r7:00000017 r6:0000007f r5:0000000b r4:9229d140
[   50.688016] [<80108a84>] (show_regs) from [<801147e0>] (__do_user_fault+0xc4/0xc8)
[   50.712379] [<8011471c>] (__do_user_fault) from [<801149f0>] (do_page_fault+0x20c/0x3a4)
[   50.737755]  r8:0000007f r7:00000017 r6:9267dc40 r5:9229d140 r4:9271bfb0
[   50.753746] [<801147e4>] (do_page_fault) from [<8010134c>] (do_DataAbort+0x44/0xc0)
[   50.779830]  r10:76f61fac r9:00000000 r8:9271bfb0 r7:0000007f r6:801147e4 r5:00000017
[   50.806897]  r4:80c09db4
[   50.819029] [<80101308>] (do_DataAbort) from [<8010cee0>] (__dabt_usr+0x40/0x60)
[   50.845699] Exception stack(0x9271bfb0 to 0x9271bff8)
[   50.860521] bfa0:                                     ffffffff 76f60210 00000010 ffffffff
[   50.887867] bfc0: 00010634 00000000 00010408 00000000 00000000 00000000 76f61fac 7e8b4c9c
[   50.915238] bfe0: 00000000 7e8b4c80 00010574 0001057c 200d0010 ffffffff
[   50.931721]  r8:10c5387d r7:10c5387d r6:ffffffff r5:200d0010 r4:0001057c
```

Can any one give me hint?

Comment: try to check mmap on MAP_FAILED, maybe its not mmap part of memory?

Comment: @NickS: I'm able to read using same mmap address

Comment: @RahulRDhobi You're reading from one offset (UCR1) but writing to a different one (UTXD) so not exactly the same address

Comment: First of all, it would help you if you printed the value that you read from UCR1. See if that value makes sense. It would also help if you printed the values of `ALLOC_SIZE`, `UCR1`, and `UTXD`, as they are not shown anywhere. Are you sure they are within the mmap'ed memory block? Another thing to check could be the arithmetic operations with a `void *` pointer. That's undefined behaviour and that's compiler-dependent. It should work in GCC, but generally I would avoid doing that, just to be on the safe side.

Comment: And while we're at it, why do you test fd, but then carry on with the program regardless of the result? If the open fails, you're up to another SEGFAULT.

Comment: You forgot to add  `if (map_base == MMAP_FAILED) perror("mmap map_base");` just after your `mmap`

Comment: And I don't think that doing that way ( accessing UART by mapping its physical base address) is the good way. UART are generally handled by *kernel* code. You probably have some `/dev/`  for it (maybe something like `/dev/tty5`), or you need to code some kernel module to get it (which might require to pause tiny delays with `nop`).  Then you'll use `ioctl` on it (in user space)

Comment: ... so I think the approach is wrong. Try to find some existing driver for hardware similar to yours, and take that as inspiration to code your own kernel module.

Comment: Perhaps it could be a delay issue. Try to add some few `asm volatile("nop");` before and after your `READ_REG32` & `WRITE_REG32` statements. However, I believe the approach is wrong: you need a kernel module

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at ‘uio’, which is a framework to help implement user mode drivers in linux.   Beyond the usual concern of synchronizing with interrupts, it also permits the platform code to ensure the right access bits are set in the page table entries for the mappings.

Some architectures, like x86, keep an associative array of physical address ranges to attributes so that things like ‘device mode’ are always properly implemented by the bus.   ARMv7 does not do this, it is the programmers responsibility to ensure that the right bus protocol is employed.  I doubt that mmap of /dev/mem does this.    The result is that your write operation may get posted as a bus operation that the device registers cannot support.

“helpful” things like the PAT are part of the reason X86 can’t be used in nice things; however the cost for ARM is borne by the programmers.

Also, *(volatile int *)x is almost meaningless as the standard that made it so, but may happen to work sometimes.